# authorize access to php project on google app engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I have a little problem with an application developed with php on google app engine.

I have developed a PHP application on Google App Engine using my Google Domain account (instead of a gmail.com address).  I would like to limit access to this application to those users within my domain.

The website is working fine but users in my domain are not able to access it.  Does anyone have any suggestions about how to get this working?

Comment: What do others see instead?  What do you see in the developer console under **Compute > App Engine > Settings > Application Settings** for authentication?  What `<security-constraint>`s (if any) do you have in your `web.xml`?

Comment: Have you tried changing the "Authentication Type" under "Application Settings" in [App Engine's admin console](https://appengine.google.com) to "Google Apps Domain"?